# How to apply Select many in the dynamic list using lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following code:

```
int count = 0;
foreach (var c in result)
{
    response.AllChecklist[0].obj.Name = c.Name;
    response.AllChecklist[0].obj.Category = c.Category;
    response.AllChecklist[0].obj.Code = c.Code;
    response.AllChecklist[0].obj.chk[count].Name = c.Name;
    response.AllChecklist[0].obj.chk[count].Type = c.Type;
    response.AllChecklist[0].obj.chk[count].chktatusCode = c.chktatusCode;
    response.AllChecklist[0].obj.chk[count].chktatusReasonCode = c.chktatusReasonCode;
    count++;
}
```

I would like to apply lambda expression. I know I should apply Select many since it has two difference class.
As part of code review, my lead suggested me to change this loop into lambda expression with `SelectMany`. I am very new to lambda expression. Any help much appreciated?

Comment: I don't understand your question. A lambda cannot be "applied", lambdas are function which can take arguments and can give something back - like methods. And `SelectMany` is a LinQ function which concats lists inside a list. And youre code does not look like as it can be improved with any LinQ code.

Comment: ya its list inside list. And My Lead told me to do selectmany linq function

Comment: Which list do you mean? `result` looks like a simple `IEnumerable<T>` whereas `T` is not an `IEnumerable`. And I don't think that `SelectMany` can improve the access to `response`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can create a new object for `response.AllChecklist[0].obj` (I don't know what previous code does), let's assume that type of `response.AllChecklist[0].obj` is `TObj` and type of `TObj.chk` is `TChk`, then you can refactor it into:

```
var lastResultItem = result.Last();
response.AllChecklist[0].obj = new TObj{
    lastResultItem.Name,
    lastResultItem.Category,
    lastResultItem.Code,
    chk = result.Select(r => new TChk{
        r.Name,
        r.Type,
        r.chktatusCode,
        r.chktatusReasonCode
    }).ToList()
});
```

But as I stated, that assumes that `response.AllChecklist[0].obj` does not have any valid data before your original code, so that you can create it safelly anew without loosing any data.

Another assumption is that assignment to `TObj.Name`, `TObj.Category` and `TObj.Code` properties does not have any other side effects then setting the property value (in your original loop you repeatedly assign to single object properties values from elements of result collection, so after the loop is done, the property values end up with corresponfing property values of the last element of `result`).